# missing javax.swing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, import

I'm trying to use the pdf library from jpedal, using the code snippet found here: http://www.jpedal.org/simple_image_example.php

```
/**instance of PdfDecoder to convert PDF into image*/
PdfDecoder decode_pdf = new PdfDecoder(true);

/**set mappings for non-embedded fonts to use*/
FontMappings.setFontReplacements();

/**open the PDF file - can also be a URL or a byte array*/
try {
        decode_pdf.openPdfFile("C:/myPDF.pdf"); //file
        //decode_pdf.openPdfFile("C:/myPDF.pdf", "password"); //encrypted file
        //decode_pdf.openPdfArray(bytes); //bytes is byte[] array with PDF
        //decode_pdf.openPdfFileFromURL("http://www.mysite.com/myPDF.pdf",false);

        /**get page 1 as an image*/
        //page range if you want to extract all pages with a loop
        //int start = 1,  end = decode_pdf.getPageCount();
        BufferedImage img=decode_pdf.getPageAsImage(1);

    /**close the pdf file*/
    decode_pdf.closePdfFile();

} catch (PdfException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But on this line:

```
decode_pdf.openPdfFile("C:/myPDF.pdf"); //file
```

Eclipse trows an error:

> The type javax.swing.JPanel cannot be resolved. It is indirectly
>   referenced from required .class files

It seems as if I'm missing javax.swing.*

Intellisence does give me other javax.* options but not the swing class.

I already searched google for this but I had no luck finding a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Usually that is part of the core java installation. Are you sure you installed it properly?

Comment: Which version/type of java are actually using?

Comment: Using the "java -version" command in cmd I got: java version "1.7.0_02"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_02-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 22.0-b10, mixed mode)

Comment: COuld you run the same code under earlier JDK? E.g. 1.6?

Comment: I'm going to try this right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't get any clearer than this:
http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2011/09/java-is-not-android/

Appears that the library I wanted to use was not compatible with android at all.

Also not the last sentence:

> that makes converting a Java PDF viewer to Android a major task.

Thanks for crushing that last bit of hope for me jpedal...

Answer (score -1):

I doubt path is not resolved, Try this

```
 decode_pdf.openPdfFile("C:\\myPDF.pdf");
```

Comment: See I also get the errors when using the other methods that where commented in the code snippet (OpenPdfArray, OpenPdfFileFromUrl)